# When I make an ajax delete request with a checkbox An error occurs in the view function

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, view

When I make an ajax delete request with a checkbox

An error occurs in the view function.

I do not know why.

Thank you if you let me know.

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\todo\views.py", line 23, in todo_delete_ajax
    todo_ids = request.POST['todo_arr']
  File "C:\django_inflearn2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 80, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'todo_arr'
```

code is below

jquery,ajax

```
$('#todo_delete_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // todo_check
    var todo_arr = [];
    alert("삭제 버튼 ")
    // Get checked checkboxes
    $('.td_check').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            var id = this.id;
            todo_arr.push(id);
        }
    });
    alert('todo_arr : '+ todo_arr)

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'todo_delete_ajax/',
      data: {
          todo_arr:todo_arr,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
      },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('todo_delete_ajax is success ');
        }
    });
})
```

url

```
    path('status/',views.todo_status_list, name ="todo_status_list"),
```

view

```
def todo_delete_ajax(request):
    # print("request " , request )
    todo_ids = request.POST['todo_arr']
    print("todo_ids : ", todo_ids)

    return redirect('/todo/')
```

Is the format of jquery ajax wrong?

Is the url pattern wrong?

Is the argument value set incorrectly?

Is the view function wrong?

Thank you if you can tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

"data" is a dictionary, and "todo_arr" is multi-valued. You might have to do a JSON.stringify() to get it to work.